# how to fly ardrone in tum simulator?

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, tum-ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i don't know how to fly the ardrone in the tum simulator and how to run the python  scripts in the simulator for the autonomy flight

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198039/how-to-fly-ardrone-in-tum-simulator-?/) by [slowmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/20904/slowmed/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2014-11-24**:
Hi, a couple of questions first. Where you able to run the simulator successfully? What topics do you get when you run `rostopic list`?

`tum_simulator` replicates the topics created by `ardrone_autonomy` to match the `ardrone_driver` node. Let me know so we can go on.

**Comment by [slowmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/20904/slowmed/) on 2014-11-26**:
thank you pedro
my response to your two questions is in the   answer below

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2014-11-26**:
I don't see in your answer the topic `/ardrone/navdata`, `/ardrone/takeoff`, `/ardrone/land`, and `/cmd_vel`. Can you confirm if you see them and forgot to include them?

**Comment by [slowmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/20904/slowmed/) on 2014-11-26**:
you saw right , they don't exist

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2014-11-26**:
What kind of error do you get? Is gazebo gui launched at all? did you install the `ardrone_autonomy` and `tum_simulator` from the fuerte branch?

**Comment by [slowmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/20904/slowmed/) on 2014-11-26**:
i install the ardrone_autonomy and the tum_simulator , gazebo does work but when i try the take off command listed in the wiki nothing happend

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2014-11-27**:
Right, you need to publish to the topics that I mentioned and you don't seem to have in order to make the ardrone move. Try reinstalling the `ardrone_autonomy` and `tum_simulator` packages. When you clone them from the git repository make sure you select the fuerte branch

**Comment by [slowmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/20904/slowmed/) on 2014-11-27**:
how do i select fuerte branch ??

**Comment by [slowmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/20904/slowmed/) on 2014-12-06**:
still nothing pedro ?

**Comment by [Pedro_85](https://answers.ros.org/users/4925/pedro_85/) on 2014-12-07**:
You can clone a particular branch from the git repository by using the flag `-b <name_of_the_branch>`. So it would be: `git clone https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy.git -b fuerte`. With tum_simulator: `git clone https://github.com/tum-vision/tum_simulator.git -b fuerte`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can fly with joystick or simply (it is very uncomfortable ) by publishing to topic.
Check [section 3.3](http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator)

---

Originally posted by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) with karma: 115 on 2014-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [slowmed](https://answers.ros.org/users/20904/slowmed/) on 2014-11-26**:
actually the command line doesn't work , i tried all the commands listed in the section 3.3 they don't work , and what i want really is to move the drone in the simulator  using  the python programs in the autonavx_ardrone  file